# JSON tips: filter objects from array of objects where object name is alpha

Tags: code-golf, array, tips, javascript, json

What could be the shortest code for filtering the following array in Javascript without any library?

My code is:

```javascript
filtered_obj = _.where(obj, { name: "Alpha" });
```

This uses a JS library called `underscore`.

Test case:

```javascript
objs = [{'id':1,'name':'Alpha'},{'id':2,'name':'Beta'},
{'id':3,'name':'Gamma'},{'id':4,'name':'Eta'},
{'id':5,'name':'Alpha'},{'id':6,'name':'Zeta'},
{'id':7,'name':'Beta'},{'id':8,'name':'Theta'},
{'id':9,'name':'Alpha'},{'id':10,'name':'Alpha'}];

filtered_obj =[{'id':1,'name':'Alpha'},{'id':5,'name':'Alpha'},
{'id':9,'name':'Alpha'},{'id':10,'name':'Alpha'}]
```

Comment: @closevoter: [Questions asking tips about golfing code are on-topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/lets-decide-what-kind-of-non-challenge-questions-we-want-once-and-for-all/1724#1724).

Comment: @LeakyNun It sure is, but without some proof of actual research from the OP, we can't say if it only is a genuine [tag:tips] question or a [tag:do-my-homework] one. Might be why someone closevoted

Comment: I used underscore which is `filtered_obj = _.where(obj, { name: "Alpha" });` then I am looking for not using any library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree with @Katenkyo and think this is a homework question in disguise.

Comment: @muddyfish Go ahead. Appreciate the help anyways.

Comment: Not sure whether is homework or should be closed, but certainly I would expect a tip to be formulated in more generic style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 45 bytes

```javascript
filtered_obj=objs.filter(n=>n.name=='Alpha');
```

This uses the [`filter` function for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/pYx19v)

Comment: please look into it http://ideone.com/p3cENn

Comment: Because I'm using spidermonkey instead of rhino.

Comment: How did you calculate the number of bytes for the solution as 45 bytes?

Comment: by counting the number of characters in `filtered_obj=objs.filter(n=>n.name=='Alpha');`.